# Permissions for $HOME/.config for snap

Tags: permissions, snap, inkscape

I have inkscape installed as a snap (https://snapcraft.io/). I am trying to save a replacement for `$HOME/.config/inkscape/templates/default.svg`, but get an error that permission is denied.

My home directory is encrypted and the permissions on `$HOME/.config` are `drwx------`.

I m running Ubuntu 18.04.

What do I need to change to allow inkscape to save this file?

Comment: Snaps don't have access to 'dot folders' in home. Can you place the default in `$HOME/snap/inkscape/current/.config/inkscape/templates` and see if that works? The snap has access to that folder

Comment: I'm having the same problem with palettes. Moving the folder into `$HOME/snap/inkscape/current/.config/inkscape/palettes` does not work for me.